# CGAL - Line segments intersection (how to get all intersection points and all intersected segments for each intersection point)

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection, cgal, segment

I have a set of Line segments in 2d (each with start and end points - (x1,y1),(x2,y2))

The CGAL example [**sweep_line.cpp**](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Sweep_line_2/index.html) shows me how to get all the intersection points of a set o segments. Because i'm not interested in only these points, also want to get all intersected segments for each intersection point. (with id or name or etc).

Comment: This [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Box_intersection_d/index.html#title4) is an alternative solution to arrangements.

Comment: Hi sloriot, thank you for your reply, but I still not understand.

Comment: Replace triangle by segment in the example (plus dimension 3->2) and the functor Report can be used to collect segments that are intersecting

Comment: Is that returns all intersection points and the line segments passing through them ?

Comment: You'll get all pairs of segments intersecting

Comment: CGAL::compute_intersection_points

I use this function , but there are not any overload of function that take Callback...